# Responsive design in divi using pixels in fonts sizes

Tags: wordpress, media-queries, responsive, divi

I have a Divi Wordpress site in which I have to use fonts sizes in pixels (cannot use rem or vw). There is a way to create a responsive site without having to write more than 20 media queries?

Comment: You could make a JS script that resize your font based on your screen size. But it's a bit lame... media queries is IMO the best way to do that

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.